# How to sort out all the database and find the right value? AngularFIRE2

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I do not know much English, so I use a translator, there may be errors((

I learn AngularFire2 and ran into a problem at this point (the fourth of five): 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md

If we scroll down, we can understand what makes this app.

By pressing the button (eg small) script comes in the items and there check item1, item2, item3, if any one of item (1,2,3) it is small, it takes its text and displays it.

(What is the problem)
And how to make brute force the entire database without giving exact values ​​check item1/2/3

That is too much to do this:
https://hsto.org/files/0a5/d13/4ba/0a5d134ba32440dcb0bd5a2f90c37c86.png

My code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      {{ item.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <h4>Filter by size</h4>
    <button (click)="filterBy('small')">Small</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('medium')">Medium</button>
    <button (click)="filterBy('large')">Large</button>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  sizeSubject: Subject<any>;

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.sizeSubject = new Subject();
    this.items = af.database.list('/items', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'size',
        equalTo: this.sizeSubject
      }
    });
  }
  filterBy(size: string) {
    this.sizeSubject.next(size); 
  }
}
```